# Cross website tags

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags, tag-wikis

I have a suggestion.

It'd be really nice if we had a way to see if the tag exists on other sites or not from the wiki page of the tag.

For example, if I'm currently viewing the "Ruby" tag, I would like to know if this tag exists on SO or gamedev or any other site, with links to the other wiki pages, of course.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What are you trying to get out of being able to see if the tag exists on other sites?

If you just want to see more questions in some set of tags, you can set up [filters](http://stackexchange.com/filters/) that will show questions with the tags specified in the filter across all (or some) Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that feature, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you got to the "tagged questions" tab of Stack Exchange and then click on "New filter" you get a page where you can create a cross site tag set.

1. Click the "Just questions tagged with the .... tag" option and enter "ruby" into the box.
2. Click the "All Sites" option.
3. Create a name.
4. Save changes.

Then you'll have a tag that shows all questions tagged "ruby". Of course in this example it will predominantly show questions from Stack Overflow.